# convergence of product

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $I$ an interval in $\mathbb{R}$

Let $f_n$  bounded  in $H^1(I),$ then we can extract a subsequence such as $f_n \rightarrow f$ strongly in $L^2(I)$

2- Let $g_n$  bounded in $L^{\infty}(I)$ , and we can extract an subsequence such as $g_n \rightharpoonup g$ weaky star in $L^{\infty}(I)$

3- and let $u_n$ such as $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ weakly in $H^1_0(I)$

my question is: How we can justify that, when we pass to a limit in the equation $g_n(x) f_n(x) = \dfrac{d u_n}{dx}$ we obtain $g(x) f(x) = \dfrac{d u}{dx}$?

Comment: In what sense of convergence is the desired limit? Point-wise? Strong? Weak?

Comment: Sorry,I edit my message. Thank's for your help

Answer (score 3):

First, we show that (a subsequence of) $f_n \, g_n$ converges weakly in $L^2(I)$. Indeed, for any $v \in L^2(I)$, we have $f_n \, v \to f \, v$ in $L^1(I)$. Hence $\int_I g_n \, f_n \, v \, dx \to \int_I g \, f \, v \, dx$. This shows $f_n \, g_n$ converges weakly in $L^2(I)$.

Moreover, $du_n/dx = u_n'$ converges weakly in $L^2(I)$ to $u'$.

Hence, the term $f_n \, g_n = u_n'$ converges weakly in $L^2(I)$ towards $f \, g$ and $u'$. We conclude $f \, g = u'$ (in the sense of a.e.).

Note that it is possible, to relax your assumptions.
Furthermore, you can also show that the whole sequence $f_n \, g_n$ converges weakly.

Comment: But why $\int_I g_n f_n v dx$ converge to $\int_I g f v dx?$

Comment: Because $f_n \, v$ converges strongly in $L^1$ and $g_n$ converges weakly-star in $L^\infty$.

Comment: But what's the theorem or property who assure this result ??please

Comment: It is a simple one-liner. $\int | f_n \, v \, g_n - f \, v \, g| \le \int | (f_n - f) \, v \, g_n | + \int | f \, v \, (g_n - g) |$. Now use the convergence properties (and the boundedness of $g_n$ in $L^\infty$).

Comment: for $\int |fv(g_n-g)|$ we say that $g_n$ weakly star converge to $g$ iff for all $v \in L^1$ $\int g_n v$ converge to $\int g v dx$ but her $fv$ isn't in $L^1$ so how we can use the weakly star convergence of $g_n$?

Comment: You have $f \in L^2$ and $v \in L^2$, hence $f \, v \in L^1$.